# How to set a java compiler in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, javac, java-7

I'm getting into Java7 development and I've added JDK7 into *Java Platforms* and have selected it in the project properties.

But when I'm compiling, I get messages like:

```
warning: java/lang/Boolean.class(java/lang:Boolean.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
```

and

```
javac: invalid target release: 1.7
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/harness/suite.xml:184: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/harness/common.xml:206: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

So as far as I understand Netbeans is using javac 1.6. How can I change in to 1.7?

### EDIT:

I'm writing a NetBeans Platform app and in main app Properties I've set: **Java Platform** = **JDK 1.7**. And in one of the module's Properties I've set **Source level** = **1.7**.

### EDIT2

- **Mac OS** 10.7.3
- **NetBeans IDE** 7.1 (Build 201112071828)
- **openjdk** version "1.7.0-internal"
- **OpenJDK** Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-internal-uko_2012_02_15_11_51-b00)
- **OpenJDK** 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b15, mixed mode)

suite.xml (184 is the second line here)

```
<target name="build" depends="-init,branding,release,-hide-excluded-modules" description="Build all modules in the suite.">
    <subant target="netbeans" buildpath="${modules.sorted}" inheritrefs="false" inheritall="false">
        <property name="cluster.path.evaluated" value="${cluster.path.evaluated}"/> <!-- Just for speed of pre-7.0 projects -->
    </subant>
</target>
```

common.xml (206 is the second line here)

```
<nb-javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.classes.dir}" debug="${build.compiler.debug}" debuglevel="${build.compiler.debuglevel}" encoding="UTF-8"
        deprecation="${build.compiler.deprecation}" optimize="${build.compiler.optimize}" source="${javac.source}" target="${javac.target}" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath refid="cp"/>
    <compilerarg line="${javac.compilerargs}"/>
    <processorpath refid="processor.cp"/>
</nb-javac>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Right click on your project --> Project Properties

Then in `Sources` set `Source/Binary Format` to JDK 7.

**EDIT 1 :**

There is a [NetBeans issue](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=203088):

Works fine in J2SE project, Web project specific problem.
The problem is that fork="false" the JDK 7.0 params are passed to JDK 6.0
compiler. The executable requires fork="true".

On the line 293 of build-iml.xml the

```
<javac 
      debug="@{debug}" 
      deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}"
      encoding="${source.encoding}" 
      excludes="@{excludes}"
      executable="${platform.javac}" 
      fork="${javac.fork}" 
      includeantruntime="false"
      includes="@{includes}"  
      source="${javac.source}" 
      srcdir="@{srcdir}"
      target="${javac.target}" 
      tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
```

should become:

```
<javac 
      debug="@{debug}" 
      deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" 
      destdir="@{destdir}"
      encoding="${source.encoding}" 
      excludes="@{excludes}"
      executable="${platform.javac}" 
      fork="yes"                          ;as opposed to ${javac.fork}
      includeantruntime="false"
      includes="@{includes}" 
      source="${javac.source}" 
      srcdir="@{srcdir}"
      target="${javac.target}" 
      tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
```

**EDIT 2 (if first tips don't work):**

Try to run Netbeans IDE in JDK7.

Edit Netbeans conf file :

**`Linux`**

> ~/.netbeans/7.0/etc/app.conf

**`Mac Os X`**

> /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/harness/etc/app.conf

Add the jdk7 path in the line `jdkhome=`.

**Or**

Launch netbeans using :

> netbeans --jdkhome /Java7/Home/dir

Comment: I'm writing a NetBeans Platform app and in main app Properties I've set: **Java Platform** = **JDK 1.7**. And in one of the module's Properties I've set **Source level** = **1.7**. So the problem is not in project setup

Comment: Check this link maybe the solution is there for you too http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=203088

Comment: Yes, but the problem is in Web apps, and I'm using Java SE. In my app, I don't have a _javac_ task in my `build.xml`. And the error points not to my ant build scripts, but to some _harness_ xmls

Comment: Ok, can you share in the question the XML lines `suite.xml:184` and `common.xml:206`? The compiler said the errors are here. And can you give your netbeans version and your os?

Comment: Have you tried to add `fork="yes"` in the `<nb-javac>` tag in common.xml? The other pb is that jdk 1.7 is still a preview for Mac Os X so you might have bugs...

Comment: A guy form Netbeans suggested running IDE in JDK7. Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: Edit the netbeans conf file, mine is at : `~/.netbeans/7.0/etc/app.conf`. Uncomment the `jdkhome=` line and set jdk7.

Comment: On mac it's in `/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/harness/etc/app.conf` but it's not working no idea why. But `netbeans --jdkhome /Java7/Home/dir` works fine and fixes the problem in some way. @alain.janinm, thank you very much for help. Can you add a solution steps from comments to your answer, so I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: Ok good! I've add in my answer what you tried. If you think of some other precisions you can also edit my post!

Comment: Thank you, thank you. An alternative work-around that won't break when build-impl.xml gets regenerated is to put the following at the top of your build.xml before it includes build-impl.xml:     `<property name="javac.fork" value="yes" />`

Answer (score 1):

Update for `NetBeans 8`:

The file to edit is

> /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\
>   8.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/harness/etc/app.conf

I added the line

```
jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk"
```

and restarted NetBeans, it accepted JDK 1.7 U67 as its compilation platform.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Netbeans 8.2 and the jdk was 1.8 and I wanted to compile the project in lower version 1.7 of Java.

- Right click on your project and go to the properties tab
- Click on libraries
- Then click on manage libraries
- After that Add platform and add your javapath and close

Then you can build your project.