# UnsupportedClassVersionError in upgrading from jdk6 to 7

Tags: java, spring, glassfish-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set a java compiler in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290848/how-to-set-a-java-compiler-in-netbeans)

I m getting the following stack-trace when i changed my jdk version in netbeans from jdk6 to 7....

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: WEB9032: Class
com.hcdc.coedp.safe.controller.GatewayController has unsupported major or 
minor version numbers, which are greater than those found 
in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.6.0_32
```

I am using glassfish 3.1.2 and spring framework.
Plz help me out.

Edit: I have edited the jdk version in glassfish asenv.bat file to jdk 7 now also getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by changing the default jdk in netbeans to JDK 7 ...this needs re-installaion  of netbeans with env variable pointing to jdk7 installation.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are compiling with JDK 1.7 but you are running with JDK (or JRE) 1.6 (ref http://goo.gl/Qsmn9).

I suggest you to check which version of JDK uses GlassFish.

Comment: i was previously using jdk 1.6 but now i want to upgrade to jdk 1.7 and i m getting this error while upgrading..

Comment: @Dario it appears that you just copied the answer from here: http://home.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/javalangunsupportedclassversionerror-web9032-class-authenticationloginbean-has-unsupported-maj-0. Please cite your answers.

Comment: @DanglingPiyush: I had the same problem when I switched to jdk 7 and the problem resided in the widzard as linked in the reference.

Comment: @Dario now m running glassfish with jdk 1.7 only than also it is not working i have already edited the question.

Comment: that message state com.hcdc.coedp.safe.controller.GatewayController is compiled with another version of JDK. Is that class compiled for runtime env 7?

Comment: @Dario yeah i have clean-build it again after changing to jdk 7.