# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError in GlassFish server?

Tags: java, glassfish

I am trying to deploy a WAR file to GlassFish server. I am getting the following error:

> [#|2013-04-06T17:50:56.982-0430|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.org.glassfish.web.loader|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB9052: Unable to load class com.tugay.User, reason: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: WEB9032: Class com.tugay.User has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.6.0_37|#]

Why is it complaining about my Java Version? I have a `@Named` annotation on the class. Does Java 1.6.0_37 not support this annotation?

```
package com.tugay.user;

import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Named("userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look closer at the package name of the error, that's `java.lang`. The problem is thus definitely not in JSF or Glassfish. It's just in basic Java SE where this package belongs to. If you'd have a JSF specific problem, you'd have gotten an exception of `javax.faces` package.

Comment: Sorry, where have you seen the package name and the exception? There is no exception here?

Comment: The [`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html). It just means that the version of the specified class is unsupported by the currently running JVM. That may happen if you have compiled the class with a newer version of the JVM, e.g. the one of Java 1.7.

Comment: What does "the version of the specified class" mean?

Comment: this refers to the class witch is actually beeing loaded by the VM. Your runtime is `1.6` and obviously you have comiled with a higher version `1.7` without explicitly specifying a target version. Recompile you code to target `1.6`. In eclipse for example you can set it with `window > settings > java > compiler > compiler compliance level > 1.6`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've compiled the `com.tugay.User` source file using Java 7 or a newer version and attempt to run it on java 6. There is a Java 7 change in the `.class` format to allow better performance on non-statically-typed languages. See [the official oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/multiple-language-support.html) for more information.

You can try to

- upgrade your production runtime to 7,
- use 1.6 to compile, or
- use `-source 1.6 -target 1.6` as modifiers to your build script

There are further explanations in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290848/how-to-set-a-java-compiler-in-netbeans).