# tools.jar issue Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Running:
    mvn install

Getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-
plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project 1: Fatal error 
compiling: 
tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\..\lib\tools.jar -> 
[Help 1]
```

Area of POM file error:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>

            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I look at C:\Program Files\Java I'm not seeing tools.jar under JRE lib folder.  I see it under JDK lib folder

Answer (score 2):

You are using a JRE, please use a JDK compile your code

[How to set a java compiler in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290848/how-to-set-a-java-compiler-in-netbeans)

Comment: Should I just change environment PATH variable to point to JDK?

Comment: Yes, change the JAVA_HOME variable and it should work fine

Comment: See also http://maven.apache.org/install.html ; add `/path/to/apache-maven/bin` to PATH, set JAVA_HOME to `/path/to/jdk` (not bin!). And no need to set M2_HOME, that's old style