# Generated servlet error: default methods are not supported in -source 1.5 (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets, netbeans-8

I am using Netbeans version 8.2 to practice my spring MVC project.The version of default IDK provided by netbeans is 1.8 , I am using this project to learn form validation. I am using all the libraries required for this project including old version , the server I am using here is GlassFish 4.1.1.

**my errors are here :**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
default methods are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
default methods are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 41 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
unknown enum constant javax.annotation.meta.When.MAYBE
  reason: class file for javax.annotation.meta.When not found

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
default methods are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
default methods are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 25 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
default methods are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
default methods are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expression not expected here

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expression not expected here

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expression not expected here

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expression not expected here

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
default methods are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expression not expected here

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 33 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1
```

**my Customer.java code  :**

```
package springdemo.mvc;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
public class Customer {

    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message="is required")
    @Size(min=2,message = "Field is required")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull(message="is required")
    @Min(value=0,message="must be greater than or equal to zero")
    @Max(value=10,message="must be less than or equal to 10")
    private Integer freePasses;

    @Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}",message="only 5 chars/digit")
    private String postalCode;
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public void setFreePasses(Integer freePasses) {
        this.freePasses = freePasses;
    }
    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public Integer getFreePasses() {
        return freePasses;
    }
    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }       
}
```

**My customer-form.jsp file :**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Customer form</title>
        <style>
            .error{color:red}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul><li>Fill out the form. Asterisk(*) means required</li></ul>
        <form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">
            First Name : <form:input path="firstName"/>
            Last Name(*) : <form:input path="lastName"/>
            <p><form:errors name="lastName" cssClass="error"/></p>
            Free Passes = <form:input path="freePasses"/>
            <form:errors name="freePasses" cssClass="error"/>
            Postal Code = <form:input path="postalCode"/>
            <form:errors name="postalCode" cssClass="error"/>
            <form:input path="submit"/>
        </form:form></body></html>
```

please help me in this.

Comment: Check your IDE setting, set the source code language level to java8 and later. `(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)`

Comment: Why are you using old versions? Modern Spring MVC uses Spring Boot.

Comment: Is it maven based project?

Comment: no it's not maven based project @Alexander Terekhov

Comment: i am using old version because I have 32bit laptop and netbeans 11 is not working properly canl you help me on that also?

Comment: Then I suppose you need to set java verson manually in Netbeans.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290848/how-to-set-a-java-compiler-in-netbeans

Comment: thanks for your help.. I will definitely try this.

Comment: There is no need to update anything... i just cleaned my project and removed my glassfish server and added it again after that my project is working properly. Thank you for your help, now my problem is solved.

Comment: So use Java 1.8. At least. 1.5 is nearly 20 years old. No reason whatsoever to still be using it.

Answer (score -1):

I got same problem after read
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

in pom.xml we need to set source and target of maven-compiler-plugin or the default is too low

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: There is nothing in your link about Java 1.5.

Comment: I think the problem is basically the same maven-compiler-plugin haven't any configuration, if you configure source and target it fixes the problem